# How to use m! in Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm learning Perl and about regular expressions for the first time so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I've been searching to find the answer for this myself but can't find anything. Maybe part of my problem is that I really don't know what it's called.

I came across a piece of code that looked like this:

```
$xl_file = "$curr_dir/$xl_file" unless $xl_file =~ ( m!(^[a-z]:)|[/\\]!i );
```

When I looked into the =~ operator I dove into the regex hole and started learning about that. But I only ever saw the "m//" matching operator. I'm assuming "m!" is another kind of matching operator but I can't find any references to it that explain how it works. Through experimentation i see that the "!i" is required when using it but that's about as much as I could figure out...

Could someone please explain this to me, or point me in the direction of some (free) material that can?

Comment: Relevant documentation can be found in perldoc perlop's [Regexp Quote-Like Operators section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) where it says, "With the `m` you can use any pair of non-whitespace (ASCII) characters as delimiters. This is particularly useful for matching path names that contain `/`, to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome)"

Comment: Of course the answer is so simple... lol. Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is the exact same thing. In Perl, you can choose regex delimiters as you like. That is,

```
m/foo/
/foo/
m!foo!
m"foo"
m+foo+
m xfoox
m{foo}
```

are all the same regex (but never use question marks as delimiter, they wake an ancient demon).

After the closing delimiter, regex modifiers are placed. The `/i` modifier activates case-insensitive matching.

For the full blast, you can dive into [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for all the hidden nuggets of Perl regexes. But for the start, [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

With matching operator, you can use any kind of delimiter, not just `/`.

So, all the below match operators are valid and do the same task:

```
m//
m!!
m{}
m##
```

Also note that, if you are using `/` as delimiter, you can remove that `m` from the beginning. So, `/foo/` is valid, but `!foo!` is not.

Comment: I think it is important to point out that this is something you should *never* do. Sure *you* know that you redefined the delimiter, but someone maintaining it after you may not.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I dissent! changing delimiters is common among multiple languages, not just Perl. It actually improves readability, as this can avoid escaping. See `/^http:\/\//` versus `m{^http://}`

Comment: @amon. Agree. Escape sequences are lot more harder to read. And that is where, using a different delimiter improves the readability.

Comment: The `{}` isn't so bad, I was more pointedly talking about `m##`, `m!!`, `m&&`, etc...

Comment: If said maintainer cannot identify `m##` as regex quote operator, he really shouldn't be maintaining perl codes.

Comment: Well, I don't feel that difficulty with them too. But again, it just depends upon the programmer.

Comment: @doubleDown You don't always get a choice as to what you have to maintain.

Comment: Personally, I find using things like s|foo|bar|g; is a nice balance between being obvious and not having to escape slashes.

Comment: Tim Toady called, he said you should probably use whatever feel like sensible delimiters for your circumstances, as long as you keep half an eye on minimising surprise for a future maintainer. // {} and ## are common, !! less so.